# 'Non-persistent' S4TF installation

Tags: swift, swift-for-tensorflow

I have followed instructions on how to install swift-for-tensorflow (CPU-version) as outlined in the github repository and the swift `REPL` works at first but also throws these warnings;

```
error: ld-2.27.so 0x7fffffff0005c564: adding range [0x1464a-0x146ba) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0x7fffffff0005c564: adding range [0x146d0-0x146d6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0x7fffffff0005c5c5: adding range [0x1464a-0x146ba) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.27.so 0x7fffffff0005c5c5: adding range [0x146d0-0x146d6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x14dc0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
```

However when I exit the terminal (Ubuntu 18.04) and re-open, running swift doesn't return the REPL instead.

The above described scenario still manifested when I initially tried installing swift (before s4tf) meaning it could be an issue with swift.

**Current solution:**
I currently have to add the path to the env. everytime I open the terminal in order to use the REPL.

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (64-bit)

Anybody with a clue on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to issue [SR-8690](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8690), which impacts Swift in general on Ubuntu. Removing libc6-dbg (`sudo apt remove libc6-dbg`) clears the error.